Converting CSV with Lat/Long to GeoJSON/GeoPackage in Pentaho
I'm new to Pentaho and trying to perform what seems like a basic spatial data conversion with Pentaho GIS Plugins. I have a CSV file containing longitude and latitude coordinates, and I'd like to convert it into a spatial format (GeoJSON or GeoPackage) using Pentaho.
Specifically, I need help with converting the coordinates into spatial features and exporting to GeoJSON/GeoPackage format.
In other GIS tools this process is usually quite straightforward, but in Pentaho I haven’t been able to find the right way to perform this basic conversion.

The project seems rather quiet, the latest commit was 4 years ago https://github.com/atolcd/pentaho-gis-plugins/commits.

The latest version is from 2022 https://github.com/atolcd/pentaho-gis-plugins/releases, but I would like to understand if up to this version it is possible to create a geographic layer from a table using this plugin.

Odd, the date of the release is two years younger that the corresponding commit https://github.com/atolcd/pentaho-gis-plugins/commit/0790087705ca9539b3042a878ebba8acb5c98063. But that is not important. The release info says "Add write to Geopackage, SVG and GPX" so it should be possible but unfortunately I cannot say how.

Finally, there was a correct answer in the official pentaho-gis-plugins repository. @darbonc provided an elegant solution in this issue. The geometry can be created using WKT format in a Select Values step:
"POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')"

This creates a WKT string that can be converted to geometry using the GIS functionality in Pentaho.
